# Communication with On-prem via second VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm struggling with configuration in GCP. I have two VPC (let's name it A nad B) located in the same project. The VPC A is connected with on-prem network via HA VPN (based on BGP). I must allow the vpc B to reach on-prem resources via vpc A. I can't extend the VPN subnet scope because of the overlap on on-prem side, so I would like to use NAT. Both vpc's are peered and are visible to each other.

I would like to reach something like this:

VPC A: 10.0.0.0/24
VPC B: 192.168.0/24

VM in vpc B (192.168.0.11) is connecting to on-prem network using VPC A where we add NAT from scope included in the tunnel (for example 10.0.0.253)

Any ideas? I will be appreciated for any hints :)